# Yii - multiple databases with one user authentication

Tags: yii

I am facing a problem trying to develop an application in Yii (v=1.1). Client wants the application to has multiple databases (one per his customer). That means that we will have unknown number of databases. Also He wants to have only one user authentication system - regard of it, users would have the choise (and the privilleges) to belong in many databases. So I am considering about the way which it could be developed.

Do you have faced something like this?

Comment: I don't think that this idea of multidatabase is a good one from where to start...

Comment: you will have to have 1 central DB where to find the users and their access to other DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should first better define your goal because it is not that clear to me what you want to accomplish, but how I see it.

Decide where you want to store the users:

- Should the same user be able to connect using the same login info to two different customer databases?
- Do you need to manage all users of all customers from one single place?

You could have the following situations:

Store users only in one common database, not in customer databases:

- when logging in tell Yii to use the "common" database for the User model
- you could have also a common application that handles user management
- you could also provide the customer with the possibility to manage his own users
- you could either have a "customer" field in the Users table to indicate to what customer it belongs, or you could have a "users_customers" table and after the login screen prompt the user with a "choose customer" screen, so one unique User can login to multiple Customers

Store users only in the customer databases:

- if you don't need for a common place to manage users, or don't need to share them between customers, simply have a User table in every Customer database, this way user "alex" could exist in both databases with different login information
- here you could simply add another field in the Login form (yes I've saw one application that does it) for example instead of Username and Password fields, ask for "Office, Username and Password", and the Office would be the name of the Customer database. Or you could even use only Username field and force users to enter something such as "alex@office" as Username, then you split that by "@" and you know to what office it belongs.
- then simply use that information both on Login screen and on session to tell Yii what customer database to connect to

So as you see it could be done in different ways. Once you choose your way, you would need a implementation.

If you don't know how to do the implementation maybe I could provide more technical information related to Yii.